# CSV chunks or off-line

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I want to generate a df from the chunks such as:

```
chunksize = 1
df_list = []
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
    df_list.append(chunk)
data_raw = pd.concat(df_list)
```

However the computer's RAM is only 3GB, and the CSV file is more than 3GB as below:

```
   a    b  c      d       e        f       g        h  i   j    ...     \
0  2    2  0  8.17680  4.76726  25.6957  1.13633    0  3  4.8   ...      
1  3    0  0  8.22718  2.35340  15.2934  1.13633    0  3  4.8   ...
```

I want to generate a df from the file by chunks in order to seperate the data to train X,  test y on some fields, such as "a-e" to train X, "g-h" to test y after that. The seperate function's inputs type is df.
Could you give some specific examples to generate a df from the chunks or a csv off-line?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `pandas.read_csv` ([documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv)). What you're looking for is a `usecols` parameter, where you can specify, which columns you want to load, say: `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` for train set.

Also specifying `chunksize` might help. Here's more info: https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk